# CSS Drop-Down Navigation Links Cramped

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I'm trying to create a responsive, drop-down CSS menu, and I have a *media query* that targets mobile devices (760 pixels). I'm trying to make all the links occupy the entire width, and that goes well, but the problem is when I display the drop down menu when the width is less than 760 pixels, all of the links of the drop down menu are cramped into the navigation links. I would like to know how to solve this problem, because I have been thinking for a long time and haven't figured out a solution. I want the drop-down menu for services to be directly below services, and the final contact link to go below the drop-down menu. This is the problem:

[image]

Below is the `HTML` and the `CSS`, as well as a link to the `JSFiddle`.

**HTML**:

```
   <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="links">
         <li id="active"><a href="#" class="link">home</a>
         </li><li><a href="#" class="link">about</a>
         </li><li><a href="#" class="link">services</a>
            <ul class="links">
               <li><a href="#" class="link2">web development</a>
               </li><li><a href="#" class="link2">design templates</a>
               </li><li><a href="#" class="link2">networking</a>
               </li><li><a href="#" class="link2">custom builds</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li><li><a href="#" class="link">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
ul.links {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
ul.links a {
    color: #737373;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.links ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
ul.links li {
    background: none;
    color: #737373;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    transition: background 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
}
ul.links ul li {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.links li:hover {
    background-color: #6ECFFF;
}
ul.links li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
ul.links li:hover .link {
    color: #F0F0F0;
}
ul.links ul li:hover .link2 {
    color: #F0F0F0;
}
#active {
    background-color: #6ECFFF;
}
#active a {
    color: #F0F0F0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    ul.links li 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    ul.links ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }

    ul.links ul li {
        background: #EBEBEB;
    }
}
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/7tkn7zzs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ul.links ul {
        position: relative;
        left: -35px; /* equal to padding left */
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. All I had to do was add (top: 22px) to counteract the bottom padding of the link.

Answer (score 2):

You should make `ul.links ul {` to `position: relative;` in media query to display it proper.

```
ul.links ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tkn7zzs/1/)**